# Read and write private variable from child contract

Tags: mapping, erc-721, string, inheritance, visibility

I have a contract `MyContract is ERC721`. `MyContract` needs to concatenate a string with an existing token URI using this function:

```
string(abi.encodePacked(_tokenURIs[_tokenId], _URI));
```

Problem is all tokens' URIs are stored in a private variable in the parent ERC721 contract like so

```
mapping(uint256 => string) private _tokenURIs;
```

**Gas efficiency is a key requirement here**. `MyContract` should not call the standard ERC721 `tokenURI` getter function: it needs a direct access to the mapping so as to concatenate the strings in one step (concatenation via `tokenURI` function would involved three steps: fetch initial URI string, concatenate appendice string, push concatenated string).

I'd like to use the standard URI functions provided by ERC721. Is this a dead-end? Can I simply change _tokenURIs mapping from `private` to `internal` and still be ERC721 compliant? Is there a work-around where I could directly overwrite `_tokenURIs` mapping from child contract?

Comment: Are you "in control" of the ERC721 contract (i.e., are you the one implementing and deploying it)? If yes, then you can declare that mapping `internal`, and then inherit from the ERC721 contract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I simply change `_tokenURIs` mapping from `private` to `internal` and still be ERC721 compliant?

Yes, the ERC721 standard (as any other standard) defines the contract's API, not its internal implementation.

> Gas efficiency is a key requirement here.

Inheritting your contract from the ERC721 contract will allow you to read that variable (after declaring it `internal`) without performing any external function calling.